Spring MVC on JBoss log errors ALSO in System.out
I have a Spring MVC application (5.2.4.RELEASE) that run on a JBoss EAP server (7.4).
When I have an error in a controller method (eg javax.naming.NameNotFoundException), the exception is logged in the server.log, and not in the application log. For logging, I use the Log4J api (version 1.2.x).
I suspect that Spring MVC expects some kind of configuration for log, but I do not have a log4j.properties file, as I have all the logging configuration put in a JBoss logging profile.
Do you know if I can configure Spring MVC logging to exclude console/system.out?
Here is an example of log I found only in server.log:
16:14:32,739 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /MyApp/test.jsp: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jboss/datasources/aaa -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.aaa
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:889)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:818)
        at org.apache.jsp.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:158)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
        [...]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jboss/datasources/aaa -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.aaa
        at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:106)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:207)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:193)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:189)
        at org.apache.jsp.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:124)
        ... 53 more


Here are the steps to reproduce the issue from scratch:

download Wildfly 23.0.2.Final (Jakarta EE Full & Web Distribution) fro this page: https://www.wildfly.org/downloads/ and unpack in a folder

setup admin user as described here: https://docs.wildfly.org/23/Getting_Started_Guide.html#authentication

using JDK 8u392-b08, start the server: the admin console is available at http://localhost:9990

create a new logging profile called 'MyLoggingProfile' that writes everything to a file

create a WAR deploy (I started from an empty Maven project) with:

[pom.xml] add JBoss BOM to 'dependencyManagement' section:

org.jboss.bom:eap-runtime-artifacts:7.4.0.GA (type pom, scope import)

org.jboss.bom:jboss-eap-jakartaee8:7.4.0.GA (type pom, scope import)



[pom.xml] add the following dependencies:

org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-impl (scope provided)
org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec (scope provided)
org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jsp:jboss-jsp-api_2.3_spec (scope provided)
org.jboss.logmanager:log4j-jboss-logmanager (scope provided)
org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.2.4.RELEASE


[web.xml] define the error page:
<error-page>
   <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
   <location>/WEB-INF/errorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>


[errorPage.jsp]:
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html> 
<head>  
   <title>Error Page</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
   <p>ERROR: ${exception}</p>  
</body\>  
</html>


[web.xml] define a Spring dispatcher servlet as (note that the Spring configuration is in a xml file):
<servlet>  
   <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>  
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
   <init-param>  
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>  
   </init-param>  
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>  
   <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>  
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>


[spring-config.xml] configure Spring MVC with ViewResolver, component-scan and annotation-driven
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
   xsi:schemaLocation="  
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"\>  
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"\>  
      <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" /\>  
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" /\>  
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /\>  
   </bean>  
   <context:component-scan base-package="it.andynaz.demo" />  
   <mvc:annotation-driven />  
</beans>


make the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file to have the line 'Logging-Profile: MyLoggingProfile' (so that the deployed application will use the indicated logging profile

create a Spring controller with these two methods (and the 'landPage.jsp' file)
  @RequestMapping("/callOK")  
  public String callWithtoutErrors(Model model) {  
      model.addAttribute("message", "My message!");  
      return "landPage";  
  }  
  @RequestMapping("/callKO")  
  public String callWithErrors(Model model) {  
      String missingJndiName = "java:jboss/datasources/aaa";  
      Context ctx = new InitialContext();  
      Context envCtx = (Context) ctx.lookup("");  
      DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup(missingJndiName);  
      if (ds == null) {  
          model.addAttribute("message", "Datasource found!");  
      } else {  
          model.addAttribute("message", "Datasource NOT found!");  
      }  
      return "landPage";  
  }




now, calling the '/callOK' url will result in the JSP page, while calling the '/callKO' url will result in the ClassCastException being logged in Wildfly 'server.log' file, instead of the application log file defined in the logging profile



This is because the error is being caught and logged by Undertow. There is currently no way to get log messages from a global module to log to your applications log context.
